# Call to other contract method return false when two parameters are passed

Tags: solidity, remix, assembly

**Caller Contract**

> Called.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("test(address, address)"),empAddress, empContAddress)

**Called Contract**

> event ad(address);

```
 function test(address e, address f)public{
     emit ad(e);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Abdul!

There is a typo in your `call` function arguments. You should remove a space from `test` function signature, i.e.

```
abi.encodeWithSignature("test(address,address)")
```

Every symbol in the string is important since the whole string is hashed in `encodeWithSignature` function.